# Andoid: handle data change in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a layout with TabLayout and ViewPager (file **refuel_order_configuration.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/refuel_order_configuration"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_only_top"
android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/gas_station_info_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refuel_order_column_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#545B6E"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="FUEL TYPE"
        android:text="FUEL TYPE"/>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/refuelOrderTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#00C2CA"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#00C2CA"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/refuelOrderViewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="330dp"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in code I add two fragments with adapter. This is the code of one of the fragments (file **refuel_order_configuration_tab.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/refuel_order_configuration_tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_only_top"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_sum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:text="1050 P" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_litres"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/taxi_text"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:text="22.9 л" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/params_seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="500"
            android:max="5000"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="#000000"
            android:progressTint="#00C2CA"
            android:thumbTint="#00C2CA" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/order_info_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sum_params_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

<!--                        <include layout="@layout/gas_column_number"/>-->

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/payment_account_label_text"
                android:textColor="#666666" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_wallet" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wallet_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:text="Bill" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_count_litres"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="50 " />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bill_configuration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:minHeight="26dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/arrow_right_gray" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:width="56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/empty_corner_background"
            android:text="@string/finish_button_text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When data changes in AppCompatSeekBar, I handle it and change data in TextView in current layout

My question:
How I may handle data change in first tab and pass it changes into TextView on second tab?

There may be a mechanism with saving the state of the tab when switching tabs and transferring this state to another tab,but I don’t know about it

Update:
I solved the problem in the following way

1. In kotlin class which initialize container Fragment (file **refuel_order_configuration.xml**) I initialize adapter

   ```
   refuelOrderViewPager.adapter = RefuelOrderConfigAdapter(fragmentManager, view.context)
       refuelOrderTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(refuelOrderViewPager)
   ```
2. In adapter class I initialize so-called DataManager and pass it into each kotlin class of tab.

   ```
   class RefuelOrderConfigAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?,
                              val context: Context) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
   private val titles: List<String> = listOf(SUM_TAB_HEADER, LITRES_TAB_HEADER)
   private val dataManager = DataManager()
   private val items: List<BaseFragment> = listOf(SumOrderConfigurationTab.instance(TabType.SUM, dataManager),
           LitresOrderConfigurationTab.instance(TabType.LITRES, dataManager))
   init {
       dataManager.registerObserver(items)
   }
   //...other adapter methods
   }
   ```
3. There is the code of DataManager. It is essentially part of the pattern Observer.

   ```
   class DataManager {

   private val observers: ArrayList<BaseFragment> = ArrayList()

   fun registerObserver(observerList: List<BaseFragment>) {
       observers.addAll(observerList)
   }

   fun notifyObservers(data: String, tabType: TabType) {
       observers.forEach { observer -> observer.handleNotify(data, tabType) }
   }
   ```

   }
4. In each class of fragment when seekBar changed I notify observers about data changed and in method handleNotify I handle data changes.

   class SumOrderConfigurationTab : BaseFragment() {

   ```
   companion object {
       private lateinit var tabType: TabType
       private lateinit var dataManager: DataManager
       fun instance(tabType: TabType, dataManager: DataManager): SumOrderConfigurationTab {
           this.tabType = tabType
           this.dataManager = dataManager
           return SumOrderConfigurationTab()
       }
   }
   ```

   //initializers, logic et.c.

   ```
   override fun bindListeners(view: View) {
       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
           override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
               leftVariable.text = seekBar?.progress.toString()
               dataManager.notifyObservers(seekBar?.progress.toString(), tabType)
           }

           override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
               leftVariable.text = seekBar?.progress.toString()
               dataManager.notifyObservers(seekBar?.progress.toString(), tabType)
           }

           override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
               leftVariable.text = seekBar?.progress.toString()
               dataManager.notifyObservers(seekBar?.progress.toString(), tabType)
           }
       })
   }

   override fun handleNotify(data: String, type: TabType) {
       if (type != tabType) {
           rightVariable.text = data
       }
   }
   ```

   }

It works. Works as expected. But

1. I think this is not the right and elegant solution.
2. There is little scope for expansion in this implementation. The solution is not flexible.

Comment: You need to add the Java/Kotlin classes

Comment: @tendai, added along with the solution

Comment: Please let me know refuel_order_configuration.xml is in activity or fragment?

Comment: @hai, it's in a fragment

Comment: 1. Init adapter by childFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager

Comment: 2. Create method notify data in parentFragment and child fragment in viewpager can call it by parentFragment. Inside parent fragment I think you easy to get child fragment by view pager adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

This solution based on popular library EventBus ([source code here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus))

Algorithm is very simple.

1. In tab Fragments in method onCreateView I register widget for listen events

   ```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.refuel_order_configuration_tab, container, false)
   }
   ```
2. Later in Fragment I create a method for receive events

   ```
   @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
   fun handleEvent(event: ChangeSumEvent) {
       // set data from event
   }

   @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
   fun handleEvent(event: ChangeLitresEvent) {
       // set data from event
   }
   ```
3. Create simple POJO classes for events

   ```
   class ChangeSumEvent(val data: Int?)
   class ChangeLitresEvent(val data: Int?)
   ```
4. In Seekbar listener i send event

   ```
   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
       override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
           return
       }

       override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
           return
       }

       override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
           //...logic for current fragment

           EventBus.getDefault().post(ChangeLitresEvent(progress)) //send event to another fragment
       }
   })
   ```
5. Finally, in method onDestroyView unregister listener.

   ```
   override fun onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView()
       EventBus().unregister(this)
   }
   ```